# Reputation_change has the historical total rather than the daily delta?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, reputation

I'm trying to use the reputation API to get the recent reputation delta for a given user. For example, looking at recent entries for `/2.2/users/21539/reputation`, one has:

```
{
    on_date: 1447018487,
    reputation_change: 2600,
    vote_type: "up_votes",
    post_type: "answer",
    post_id: 303231,
    user_id: 21539
}
```

It's showing a huge reputation change of 2600 for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303216/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-perl/303231#303231), which is the total reputation gain since the answer was written in 2008 (10 x 260). Instead, I expected it to be just 10, for the upvote that happened on that one day.

Or am I misunderstanding the semantic of this field? If so, how would I get the recent delta, as is displayed on the reputation tab for a user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit confusing but that is not a bug.
Think of it as, "Reputation *change* from **when** to **when**?"

Since you specified neither a `fromdate`, nor a `todate`, you are effectively asking for the changes for all time.

If you run the query for Nov 1, 2015 to Nov 9, 2015:

[/2.2/users/21539/reputation?fromdate=1446336000&todate=1447027200](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users#fromdate=2015-11-01&todate=2015-11-09&ids=21539&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

You get:

```
"on_date": 1447018487,
"reputation_change": 10,
"vote_type": "up_votes",
"post_type": "answer",
"post_id": 303231,
"user_id": 21539
```

Which agrees with [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/303216/timeline):

[image]

Reference:

- [the doc page for `/users/{ids}/reputation`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users)
- [The `reputation` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/reputation)

See also, [the `/users/{ids}/reputation-history` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-history).

Comment: Indeed, that works! So as I understand, it takes all the events for a given answer in the date range, and creates a single entry that is dated as the last event within the range. e.g. if the range is October 1 to 31, and a question gets an upvote on the 3rd, 10th and 17th, it'll show as a reputation_change of 30 on the 17th, Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes. And, a post will have a separate entry for each event type that occurred in that range. EG: `up_votes` (hint, hint :) ), `bounties_won` (wink & nudge), `suggested_edits`, etc.

Comment: Got it. Now here is the most meta link you'll see today: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users#fromdate=2015-11-10&todate=2015-11-11&ids=7653&filter=default&site=stackapps&run=true :)